# QXmlStreamWriter replaces some characters by '\0'

Tags: xml, qt, qt5, qtcpsocket

I'm using `QTcpSocket` and `QXmlStreamWriter`. I use `XmlWriteAttribute` to add some attribute to current element. In large transfers, after a while (and randomly) some part of this attribute values not written correctly and substituded by some `'\0'` chars.

example:

```
<element name="something"> .....</element>
```

damaged and written like this

```
<element name="\0\0\0ething">.... </element>
```

'\0\0\0' is not visible, but I want to visualize them :)

Why?

My code is something like this:

```html
void MyXMLGenerator(QXmlStreamWriter * stream, bool isCmd, const QString commandName, const QString cmdText, TXMLParams params, qint64 cmdId)
{
    if (isCmd)
    {
        stream->writeStartElement("cmd");
    }
    else
    {
        stream->writeStartElement("status");
    }


    stream->writeAttribute("name", commandName);
    stream->writeAttribute("cmd_id", QString("%1").arg(cmdId));
    ...
}
```

Comment: Without the code, it's hard to tell. Did you check the data in the socket is valid?

Comment: @Tarod Thanks, I added my code part that caused that bug.I have read socket packets by wireshark and surely that function is the bad spot. And I'm sure that one thread is writing on that socket.

Comment: Are you writing into a file? You could try to write into a `QString` and check if you get the same issue.

Comment: I would investigate about encoding

Comment: My friends @Tarod ,Giancarlo pay attentiond that this event happens at random instances and not regular.